# Duplicating a Tkinter treeview

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to display a ttk treeview in another window. The only option, it seems, is to iterate through the original treeview and populate the new one accordingly.

However I can't seem to get all the (many) subfolders in the right place, everything is mixed up as of the 2d level (i.e., I get the root folders and their children right, and after that the subfolders seem to be inserted at random locations).

The function is :

```
    def getsubchildren(item=''):
        children = []
        for child in original_treeview.get_children(item):
            i = new_treeview.insert(item, 'end', text=original_treeview.item(child) 
                                   ['text'],values=original_treeview.item(child)['values'])
            children.append(i)

        for subchild in children: 
            getsubchildren(subchild)
```

And calling the function with `getsubchildren(item='')`, to start iterating from the first level.
There must be something I'm doing wrong, but I can't identify the issue and my attempts at modifying the function have only given a poorer result.
Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Why wouldn't I ? :)
It started as an option in fact, to select a destination folder for moving or copying files or folders. Sounded better, from an ergonomy standpoint, than selecting on the main treeview.
Since I couldn't pull it off and I'm apparently the stubborn type, here I am.
Essentially, I do have another option, but I'd like to have a solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without known the depth of the item you need to check if the item has children. If so you need the function to call itself in a loop. Here is a working exampel:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

maintree = ttk.Treeview(root)
maintree.pack()

first = maintree.insert("","end",text='first')
second= maintree.insert(first,"end",text='second')
third= maintree.insert(second,"end",text='third')
fourth= maintree.insert(third,"end",text='fourth')

st = maintree.insert("","end",text='1st')
nd= maintree.insert(st,"end",text='2nd')
rd= maintree.insert(nd,"end",text='3rd')
th= maintree.insert(rd,"end",text='4th')

top = tk.Toplevel(root)
subtree = ttk.Treeview(top)
subtree.pack()

def copy_item_tree(item,child):
    for child in maintree.get_children(child):
        item = subtree.insert(item,"end",
                              text=maintree.item(child)['text'])
        if maintree.get_children(child):
            copy_item_tree(item,child)
def copy_tree():
    for child in maintree.get_children():
        item = subtree.insert("","end",text=maintree.item(child)['text'])
        copy_item_tree(item,child)

button = tk.Button(root,text='Copy Tree', command=copy_tree)
button.pack(fill='x')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm however not sure this will work if there are multiple children in each child? I'll try it out tomorrow and give feedback.

Comment: it works, and flawlessly so. Many thanks for the assistance. I'm marking your answer as the solution.